# Не переведено сообщение об откате правки автором

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, ревизии

> Edit approval overridden by post owner or moderator

[image: скриншот]

Ссылка на подобное сообщение в истории ревизий: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/679346/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Перевёл так](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/111735025?key=372340e59496451cec6ed844ffa9bc23):

> Принятая правка отменена автором сообщения или модератором

Будет доступно после подкачки transifex и пересборки сайта.