# Edit approval overridden by post owner or moderator

Tags: дефект, локализация, нет-в-transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/712395/revisions

> Откат к версии 1 - Edit approval overridden by post owner or moderator

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Данная строка [переведена](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93LnI.png) уже как 3 месяца назад. Видимо, где-то движок не подхватил. Надо писать на MSE.

Comment: @alexolut, о, нашёл о_О https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5327/178988 Но ведь тогда работало же?

Comment: Точно работало?

Comment: @alexolut, ну мне так кажется...

Comment: видимо, только кажется.

Comment: Запулил баг на MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300363/339911

Comment: @alexolut, пофиксили.

Comment: Вот что <s>крест</s> MSE животворящий делает.